# PageModel.RedirectToPage() throws InvalidOperationException when called without /Index page

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

ReturnUrl property contains the relative url which was called before in the following manner:

```
var returnUrl = HttpContext.Request.Path.Value;
```

Whenever the former url was pointing to a directory which contains an Index.cshtml page, it does not include the Index.cshtml but only the directory path. E.g. '/PersonManagement' instead of '/PersonManagement/Index'

The following code leads to an InvalidOperationException: No page named '/PersonManagement' matches the supplied values:

```
    public IActionResult OnPostSaveCurrentLiquidity()
    {
      // ... any other code

      return RedirectToPage(ReturnUrl);
    }
```

Is there any way to redirect to an Index page within the application existing in the mentioned directory without explicitly extending the ReturnUrl by '/Index'?
If this is  not possible, is there any way to figure out the whole relative url path including the 'Index' when the page was called as follows: 'https://myhost/PersonManagement' instead of 'https://myhost/PersonManagement/Index'?

Thanks a lot for any hint

Comment: It appears you could use `LocalRedirect(ReturnUrl)` here instead.

Comment: Hi Kirk. Exactly that does the trick. Thank you!